# Running javascript on more than one form that is on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to building websites and need some help. I have three forms on a page. Two of the forms are modals. I have trying to run java script on all of the them. But it looks like the java script will only run on the form that is used first. Could anyone tell me where i am going wrong. Below is my code

```js
$(function() {

  // Get the form.
  var form = $('#ajax-contact');
  var form = $('#ajax-enquires');
  var form = $('#ajax-cv');

  // Get the messages div.
  var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

  //Hide image on page load
  $('#loader').hide();

  // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // disable button double submits
    $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);

    // Show image before making ajax call
    $('#loader').show();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        // Hide always after every request
        $('#loader').hide();
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        //Remove message after x seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(formMessages).text('');
          $(formMessages).removeClass('success')
        }, 3000);

        //rest form
        $("#ajax-contact")[0].reset();
        $("#ajax-enquires")[0].reset();
        $("#ajax-cv")[0].reset();

        // enable button 
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', false);

      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        // Hide always after every request
        $('#loader').hide();
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
          $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }

        //Remove message after x seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(formMessages).text('');
          $(formMessages).removeClass('error')
        }, 5000);

        // enable button 
        $("#con-submit").attr('disabled', false);

      });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles_test.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>


  <div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64">
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-32 w3-section">
      <div class="w3-col m8 w3-container w3-section">
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="POST" action="php/contact.php">
          <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <textarea class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="message"></textarea>
          <button class="w3-btn w3-gold w3-right w3-padding w3-section" type="submit" id="con-submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
        </form>
        <div id="form-messages"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-left w3-display-container w3-center" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="w3-padding-xlarge">
      <button class="w3-btn w3-white w3-padding-large w3-large w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" onclick="document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display='block'">SUBMIT CV</button>
      <button class="w3-btn w3-gold w3-padding-large w3-large w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" onclick="document.getElementById('client').style.display='block'">CLIENT ENQUIRES</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Subscribe Modal -->
  <div id="subscribe" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-padding-jumbo">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <i onclick="document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-xlarge w3-closebtn w3-hover-text-grey w3-margin"></i>
        <h2 class="w3-wide">SUBMIT YOUR CV TODAY</h2>
        <p></p>
        <form id="ajax-cv" method="POST" action="php/cv.php">
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Full Name" required name="name"></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email"></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Telephone Number" required name="number"></p>
          <p><input type="file" name="cv" accept="file_extension|.doc"></p>
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="w3-btn-block w3-padding-large w3-gold w3-margin-bottom">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Client Enquires Modal -->
  <div id="client" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-padding-jumbo">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <i onclick="document.getElementById('client').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-xlarge w3-closebtn w3-hover-text-grey w3-margin"></i>
        <h2 class="w3-wide">CLIENT ENQUIRES</h2>
        <p></p>
        <form id="ajax-enquires" method="POST" action="php/enquires.php">
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Full Name" required name="name"></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email"></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Telephone Number" required name="number"></p>
          <p><textarea class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Message" required name="message"></textarea></p>
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="w3-btn-block w3-padding-large w3-gold w3-margin-bottom">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/contact.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `form` variable with each successive form. If you want to put multiple forms in a single jQuery object, separate their selectors with a comma, like this: `var form = $('#ajax-contact, #ajax-enquires, #ajax-cv');` Also use the `this` keyword instead of the `form` variable inside the `click()` event handler

Comment: Put your code in a function, and call that function *when* and *where* you need your code to run. That probably is some event handler. You can call the function as many times as you need, you can pass the form as parameter if needed. Edit: what Rory says works too, use selector to pick the forms you need. I wanna say that's more specific to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you're doing here:

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact');
var form = $('#ajax-enquires');
var form = $('#ajax-cv');
```

After all three of those lines, what do you expect the `form` variable to be?  Whatever you *last* set it to.

If you want `form` (or more appropriately `forms`) to select all three of those, set it once with a selector that identifies all three:

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact, #ajax-enquires, #ajax-cv');
```

Then when you're setting your submit handler, it'll be set to all three of those matching elements.

Note also that inside your submit handler you're not going to want to reference the `form` variable the way that you are.  Instead, use `this` so each instance of the handler knows which matching form to use.  For example:

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: @KMD but your html is still false ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  // do something
  $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

allready tried something like this?

you overwrite your var form everytime.

```
<form id="form1">
    <button type="submit">btn1</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <button type="submit">btn2</button>
</form>
```

and in your html is a failure too, id's are only for use once. you use `id="submit"` in every form. better to kill the id property and use `$(this).find('button[type="submit"]')` in your js code

Comment: Could you explain why my HTML is false as the forms all work now. Newbie over here :)